# Python - Pandas - GroupBy conditional string addition

Tags: python, string, pandas, group-by

Currently I'm having trouble setting up a combination of setting up a list and filtering when grouping a dataframe.

Let's say we have a DataFrame of the form:

```
      A       B    C
0    x2   a32cd    1
1    x1   a11aa    0
2    x1     NaN    1 
3    x1   d75dd    0
4    x1   a11aa    1
5    x2   a32cd    1
6    x2   w22xz    0
...
```

And what I'm looking for is to group on column `A` (strings) and then make a list of **non-duplicate**, **non-null** values of `B` (strings) and I can drop out list `C` (integers). The final form I am looking for is something like:

```
      A           B 
0    x1   [a11aa, d75dd, ...]
1    x2   [a32cd, w22xz, ...]
```

I was thinking of setting it up somehow with the form of:

`df_x.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list)`

and then apply some conditions to it, but I can't seem to find it. Should I set up a function for it? I come from a MATLAB based background, so I am inclined to just run through the entire DataFrame, row by row. But I have been told that once you are thinking about doing that in Pandas that there probably is a smarter way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't want to `dropna` right upfront (losing information on other columns, such as `C`).

So you can `groupby` and `agg` with your logic for `B` only

```
df.groupby('A').B.agg(lambda s: s.dropna().unique().tolist())

A
x1    [a11aa, d75dd]
x2    [a32cd, w22xz]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: Ummm , I will give a help.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Indeed I needed empty lists in case there were only `NaN`s associated with the `A` column. :) Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks Wen, I appreciate your help :) @SirGianmarcoD Glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> df.dropna().groupby("A")["B"].unique()
A
x1    [a11aa, d75dd]
x2    [a32cd, w22xz]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great, except what I failed to mention was that indeed the dropping out of rows where `NaN`s occurs is undesirable. In that case I would like an empty list (like `[]`) to pop up. The other answer provided this. Sorry that I failed to mention this. Thanks for you help anyways! :)